# Extracting dates with format '%D %d, %Y' from a string

Tags: python, datetime, python-re

I was trying to extract the date from a string with the format `'%D %d, %Y'` (e.g. `'November 1, 1960'` from `'November 1, 1960 ( 1960-11-01 )'`).

Now I have:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

word_months = r'January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December'
word_day_year = r'\d+,\s\d{4}'
word_date = rf'{word_months}({word_day_year})'
s = 'November 1, 1960 ( 1960-11-01 )'
re.search(word_date, s).group()
```

I have the output be `'November'` instead of `'November 1, 1960'`. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Use a regex debugger: https://regex101.com/r/5IRUt1/1.

Comment: Where is the code that creates the output?

Comment: Try `word_date = rf'((?:{word_months})\s(?:{word_day_year}))'` instead: you want a capturing group covering whole `November 1, 1960`, but don't want `word_day_year` to apply only to `December`. Just `print(word_date)` to see what your f-string formatting gave: it's `January|...|November|December(\d+,\s\d{4})` - you're missing a whitespace, and last group applies to `December` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the months, and account for the space after the month / before the day.

Consider limiting the day to two digits, and grouping both the day and the year for further validation.

```py
import re

word_months = r'(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)'
word_day_year = r'\s(\d{1,2}),\s(\d{4})'
word_date = rf'{word_months}{word_day_year}'

m = re.search(word_date, 'November 1, 1960 ( 1960-11-01 )')

print(f'Primary match: <{m.group()}>')
print('Sub matches:')

for g in m.groups():
    print(f'<{g}>')
```

```
Primary match: <November 1, 1960>
Sub matches:
<November>
<1>
<1960>
```

Also consider [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match), or otherwise anchor the expression (if appropriate).